Chain halts after runtime upgrade | Getting `Ignoring empty epoch change.` `Error with block built on`
I have a solo chain using Babe consensus. In my new branch, I implemented OneSessionHandler in one of my pallets. I am using this to collect active validators.
It's working fine if I run chain with my new branch. But if I do runtime upgrade on main branch, I started getting below error when new session changes:
2024-07-18 15:46:12 Corrupted state at `[206, 197, 7, 13, 96, 157, 211, 73, 127, 114, 189, 224, 127, 201, 107, 160, 224, 205, 208, 98, 230, 234, 242, 66, 149, 173, 76, 207, 196, 29, 70, 9]: Error`    
2024-07-18 15:46:12 Ignoring empty epoch change.    
2024-07-18 15:46:12  Prepared block for proposing at 34 (0 ms) [hash: 0xfe09b1a95631607aebada259e1a6adde43c64f4162e7fc33ae7468f42582157b; parent_hash: 0x4194…62e8; extrinsics (1): [0x6084…214a]    
2024-07-18 15:46:12  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 34. Hash now 0x73c962d1c74905a331ec6f81ce6bad5abf20d3bffc428846c3b8a43698d2dfcb, previously 0xfe09b1a95631607aebada259e1a6adde43c64f4162e7fc33ae7468f42582157b.    
2024-07-18 15:46:12 Error with block built on 0x419470202271cf7ba8e482c437226dc3201627ac9a7890f420b25506103162e8: Import failed: Expected epoch change to happen at 0x73c962d1c74905a331ec6f81ce6bad5abf20d3bffc428846c3b8a43698d2dfcb, s286882962    
^

After above error, chain stops producing blocks.
Here is my OneSessionHandler implementation:
impl<T: Config> sp_application_crypto::BoundToRuntimeAppPublic for Pallet<T> {
        type Public = T::AuthorityId;
    }

    impl<T: Config> OneSessionHandler<T::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
        type Key = T::AuthorityId;

        fn on_genesis_session<'a, I: 'a>(validators: I)
        where
            I: Iterator<Item = (&'a T::AccountId, Self::Key)>,
        {
            let validators = validators
                .map(|(_, k)| T::AccountId::decode(&mut &k.into().encode()[..]).unwrap())
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();

            ValidatorSet::<T>::put(validators); 
        }

        fn on_new_session<'a, I: 'a>(_changed: bool, validators: I, _queued_authorities: I)
        where
            I: Iterator<Item = (&'a T::AccountId, Self::Key)>,
        {
            let validators = validators
                .map(|(_, k)| T::AccountId::decode(&mut &k.into().encode()[..]).unwrap())
                .collect::<Vec<_>>();
            ValidatorSet::<T>::put(validators);
        }

        fn on_disabled(_i: u32) {}
    }
}

I also added corresponding changes in runtime.
impl_opaque_keys! {
    pub struct SessionKeys {
        pub grandpa: Grandpa,
        pub babe: Babe,
        pub im_online: ImOnline,
        pub authority_discovery: AuthorityDiscovery,
        pub template_module: TemplateModule,
    }
}

I haven't made any change related to epoch. Also if I remove last key from above SessionKeys, then it works fine but it does not call on_new_session method of OneSessionHandler.
Can somebody please help to fix this?

When you change the format of your SessionKeys, you need to write a migration. See this pull request for an example SessionKey migration (the pull request is actually removing the migration, but it shows you exactly the code that was used).

Great Thanks for your answer. The above error is gone now after implementing migration approach. BUT now it's not replacing with new validator keys during new session.
For example:  let's take beefy example. After successful migration, If I insert new key using author_insertKey and value beef>>public_key, it should be fetched in new session. please let me know if I am missing something.

Sorry, I don't really get the question. author_insertKey only adds a key to the local keystore, not more. This doesn't change anything on chain. If you want to change your key on chain, you need to send the Session::set_keys transaction.
